# how to group by and add min field in the result

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, google-bigquery

I have this kind of table

```
currency| platform | rank
---------------------------
EUR/USD | UBS      | 1
EUR/USD | DB       | 2
USD/JPY | JP       | 1
USD/JPY | MS       | 2
```

I want to query and get the flowing results

```
currency| platform | rank
---------------------------
EUR/USD | UBS      | 1
USD/JPY | JP       | 1
```

So my query looks like this

```
select currency,min(rank)
from xxx
group by currency
```

How do I get the matching platform in my results too?

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to solve this problem is using the `group_concat()`/`substring_index()` trick:

```
select currency,
       substring_index(group_concat(platform order by rank), ',', 1) as platform,
       min(rank)
from xxx
group by currency;
```

This should work on reasonable data.  If you have lots and lots of data, you have to be careful about the parameter that specifies the maximum length of the `group_concat()` result.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution with BigQuery - it has NEST aggregation function to create REPEATED (aka ARRAY), which makes it more "relational" than GROUP_CONCAT:

```
select currency, first(platform) within record, rank from (
select currency, nest(platform) as platform, min(rank) rank from
(select 'EUR/USD' currency, 'UBS' platform, 1 rank),
(select 'EUR/USD' currency, 'DB' platform, 2 rank),
(select 'USD/JPY' currency, 'JP' platform, 1 rank),
(select 'USD/JPY' currency, 'MS' platform, 1 rank)
group by 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

On the other hand, I think the group_concat function is anathematic to the very idea of relational databases! Anyway, you were quite close... just join your subquery back to the table...

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM xxx a
  JOIN 
     ( select currency,min(rank) min_rank
         from xxx
        group 
           by currency
     ) b
    ON b.currency = a.currency
   AND b.min_rank = a.rank
```